# Is there any difference between a normal person and a jivan muktha except perception?

Tags: moksha, mukti

In some texts like Yoga Vasista, I read that, normal persons have physical perception aka **stula drishti** and jivan mukthas has unified/ultimate perception aka **tatva drishti**. I am interpreting it as the difference in mental level **only**.

I personally believe that there may be so many differences between a normal person and a jivan muktha apart from perceptional differences. Jivan mukthas may have several capabilities at the physical level also. For example, Goddesses appear to rescue Jada Bharata. No punishment made Prahlada suffer. [Vasishta did not die although he attempted suicide](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42649/vasishta-attempting-suicide-unsuccessfully).

Is it true that there is only a perceptional difference between a normal person and jivan muktha?  Is the perceptional difference the only difference or one of the differences? Or do the other differences appear automatically due to the perceptional difference?