# What are the other instances where death or pain is not experienced by individual?

Tags: scripture, death

There are some instances in scriptures, where an individual is not experiencing either death or *pain* due to some qualities, such as being jivan muktha etc.,

I know two such instances: Prahlada, [Vasista](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42649/661).

Are there any other such instances in scriptures?