# Instances of doing physical tasks by will in ancient texts

Tags: scripture, nala

In recent modern texts of sanathan dharma that cover the life history of a sidda or sadhaka, we can come across several instances of miracles. My question is restricted to the miracles of ***doing activities at will without involving manually***.

But afaik, they are relatively rare in ancient texts such as Puranas, ithihasas, etc., I have an example of one such miracle instance I want to know more such

> And Kesini said, 'O Damayanti, a person of such control over the
> elements I have never before seen or heard of. **Whenever he cometh to
> low passage, he never stoopeth down, but seeing him, the passage
> itself groweth in height so that he may pass through it easily. And at
> his approach, impassable narrow holes open wide**. King Bhima had sent
> various kinds of meat--of diverse animals, for Rituparna's food. And
> many vessels had been placed there for washing the meat. **And as he
> looked upon them, those vessels became filled (with water).** And having
> washed the meat, as he set himself to cook, he took up a handful of
> grass and held it in the sun, when fire blazed up all on a sudden.
> Beholding this marvel, I have come hither amazed. Further, I have
> witnessed in him another great wonder. O beauteous one, he touched
> fire and was not burnt. **And at his will, water falling floweth in a
> stream.** And, I have witnessed another greater wonder still. He took up
> some flowers, began to press them slowly with his hands. And pressed
> by his hand, the flowers did not lose their original forms, but, on
> the contrary, became gayer and more odorous than before. Having beheld
> wonderful things I have come hither with speed.'"
>
> [[Section 75, Nalopakhyana Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03075.htm)

You can observe the words of Kesini in what she watched. The bolded ones signify that Nala has the capability of doing (some) tasks at will without involving himself manually.

Although there are some instances, such as fire didn't burn his hands, it can be seen in the stories of Prahlada, [Vasista](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42649/vasishta-attempting-suicide-unsuccessfully), etc.,  I am not asking for such ones in this question.

Are there any other such instances in ancient texts where a person can do activities by will without involving manually?

Comment: The creation of *Mānasaputras* (mind-born sons of Brahmā) in Viṣṇu and Bhāgavata Purāṇas is one e.g. , after all he didn't do anything manually to have them, and were literally created with just his intention and mind. But then Brahmā is a deity and not a person (human) as such, so I am not sure if that would be an apt example.

Comment: @Bingming I am asking for humans only, Nala is a human being.

Comment: I’ve come across this hundreds of times in different Hindu mytho stories in different situations. Inanimate stuffs, objects will changes to suit the person so that they don’t manually do anything. But things around them moving to help them or do what they want. Will try post further comment if I can come up w/ specifics examples. But yeah I think is common phenomenon for people who are yogi types at a high level, who are accomplished, have achieved a lot in spiritual attempts.